# Spring Boot reference on old entity version

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a problem with Spring Boot. I have a Schema.sql in resources folder and an entity. At the first app run everything works as desired. But as I changed the column names in schema.sql, updated my Entity, deleted the database table and re-run the app, Spring creates always the old Entity column names.

In my application.properties I have the following entries:

```
spring.datasource.name                   = mydatasource
spring.datasource.url               = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?serverTimezone=UTC&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name      = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.password               = password
spring.datasource.username               = username

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

security.oauth2.client.clientId= my_client
security.oauth2.resource.id= myid
security.oauth2.client.clientSecret= my_srcret
security.oauth2.client.accessTokenUri= http://localhost:8080/api/oauth/token
security.oauth2.client.userAuthorizationUri= http://localhost:8080/api/oauth/authorize
security.oauth2.resource.token-info-uri=http://localhost:8080/api/oauth/check_token

logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
```

My new Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "organizers")
public class Organizer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "commercialName")
    private String commercialName;
    @Column(name = "org_description")
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "verified")
    private boolean verified;
    @Column(name = "isOnline")
    private boolean isOnline;
    @Column(name = "org_type")
    private OrganizerType type;
    @Column(name = "alias")
    private String alias;
    @Column(name = "fone")
    private String fone;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private User user;
}
```

My new Schema.sql

```
create table if not exists organizers
(
    id             bigint PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    userId         varchar(256)             not null,
    commercialName varchar(100)       not null,
    description    varchar(1000)      not null,
    verified       boolean default 0,
    isOnline       boolean default 0,
    type           int                not null,
    alias          varchar(100)       not null,
    fone        varchar(100)       not null,
    constraint fk_user_id FOREIGN KEY (userId) REFERENCES users (username)
);
```

Here is a screenshot what Spring created:

[image]

As you can see in the picture, Spring create always the organizers table based on my old Schema and Entity! I am using Spring Boot version 2.1.6 with MySql version 8.0.17

I thought Spring Boot caches always my old Schema.sql or my old Entity! What could the problem be?

Comment: Hope you have only one Schema.sql in your project.

Comment: Yes i have only one

Comment: is the question for `org_type` column?

Comment: No generally. I solved the problem by setting jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl and removed dll-auto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

is set to `update` so hibernate updates your schema, it should be removed completely so flyway can create the schema from `schema.sql`.

In addition you need to add the following configuration to enable the schema creation from flyway:

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

From the documentation [Database Initialization](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html)

> In a JPA-based app, you can choose to let Hibernate create the schema or use schema.sql, but you cannot do both. Make sure to disable spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto if you use schema.sql.

In addition you have an error in your entity mapping. The new Entity references the column `@Column(name = "org_description")` but in your new schema definition the column is called just `description`, you need to update your column mapping once your schema creation works.

Comment: Thank you for the hint about my mistake. I removed spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update from application.properties and updated column names. But now spring does not create the tables

Comment: try to set the property spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always and read through the whole documentation.

Comment: Thank you i set spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always

and spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl and its working now

Comment: as you are using @Column annotations on every field, you don't event need to overwrite the naming strategy. It should work the same without setting the naming strategy. I added the spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always into my answer. Feel free to accept an answer, which helped you most.

Answer (score 2):

It's not referencing the old entity version, it just looks like that. Set spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy in application properties.

By default sprin guses org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.SpringNamingStrategy. This will convert anything like commercialName (in camel case) to commerical_name. Setting the above property will override this behaviour.

Comment: i set spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy but does not help. This property is deprecated

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten that was deprecated. Can you try ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl from https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-naming-strategy

Comment: now i have another problem when i try to save an entity: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'commercial_name' in 'field list'. The column names in the Table and Entity are in camelCase. But where did spring get this snake_case i dont know

Comment: i solved it by changing the strategy to spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl thank you